# Django - performance of using related model fields

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have two related models

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    value = models.FloatField()

class Bar(models.Model):
    multiplier = models.FloatField()
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name="bars")

    def multiply(self):
        return self.foo.value * self.multiplier
```

An instance of Foo will frequently have many instances of Bar, but some information that is relevant for a calculation that Bar does is stored in Foo (because it is the same for all instances of related Bars)

The problem is when I do something like this:

```
foo = Foo.objects.latest()
[x.multiply() for x in foo.bars.all()]
```

It ends up hitting the database a lot because every Bar object in foo.bars.all() queries the database for the Foo object.  So, if I have 10 Bars, then I will incur 11 database queries (1 to get the queryset with 10 bars, and 1 for each Bar object reaching back to get self.foo.value).  Using select_related() doesn't seem to help.

My questions are:
  1) Am I correct in thinking that memcached (e.g. Johnny Cache, Cache Machine) will solve this problem?
  2) Is there a way of designing the object relationship that can make the command more efficient without a cache?

Comment: why would it be 11 queries? it would be just 2 queries.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, should be [x.multiply() for x in foo.bars.all()].  Because multiply() requires a value that is stored in foo, so each call of multiply() has to retrieve foo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is precisely this kind of situation for which [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) were created. When you query using these, Django's ORM will employ one of two techniques to avoid redundant database requests: following relations via JOINs (`select_related`) or pre-caching one-to-many / many-to-many relations in their QuerySets.

```
# Hits the database
foo = Foo.objects.prefetch_related('bars').latest()

# Doesn't hit the database
[x.value for x in foo.bars.all()]
```

Comment: prefetch_related() was it.  Thanks!